# PHP Error: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists

Tags: php, session, apache2

Getting the following error when trying to start a session:

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists in file.php on line 3`

The script uses SimpleXML to parse XML files from remote hosts. It's running on a Linux Ubuntu server with PHP 5.2.6.

Has anyone come across this message before or have an insight in to what it means?

Comment: @Gumbo Me personally or the script?

Comment: Well, since we’re talking about your script …

Comment: It just reads an XML file using SimpleXML object and then stores some of the values as SESSION variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See explanation at the bottom of [this page](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49275&edit=1)

```
[2009-09-25 11:41 UTC] rrichards@php.net

Thank you for taking the time to write to us, but this is not
a bug. Please double-check the documentation available at
http://www.php.net/manual/ and the instructions on how to report
a bug at http://bugs.php.net/how-to-report.php

Cannot serialize object wrapping 3rd party library structs. Must 
serialize the xml (to a string) and store that to session and reload the 
xml when restoring from session
```

Answer (score 3):

Start here:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/831550-session_start-node-no-longer-exists

It looks like the variable you're working with isn't an array or variable in the traditional sense: it acts more like a resource. You're going to have to loop out the values like you might with a MySQL $result.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store SimpleXML results in a session. Convert it to an array or extend it with wake and sleep magic methods.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and got a fix from the site http://www.ossramblings.com/simple_xml_breaks_sessions

Actually the session will not work well while trying to store XML data, so just convert the XML data (I mean objects) to a string as below:

```
$temp_max_markers = (string)$Response->owner->max_markers;

$_SESSION['max_markers'] = $temp_max_markers;
```

Answer (score 0):

also u cannot use the `xml` in session name as .. `$_SESSION[xml];`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encryption key in config file in application folder in codeigniter it works for me..