# Getting Error while using SESSIONS in PHP

Tags: php

I am passing some values through a SESSION variable as below

Page 1: (creating the session variables)

```
<?php
session_start();
<html code Come here>
$_SESSION['fname']=$fn;
$_SESSION['fimg']=$fim;
$_SESSION['fnum']=$fnum;
$_SESSION['from']=$fl;
$_SESSION['to']=$tl;
?>
```

Page 2: (Printing the  values of that Session variables)

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['fname'];
echo $_SESSION['fimg'];
echo $_SESSION['fnum'];
echo $_SESSION['from'];
echo $_SESSION['to'];
?>
```

Now when i am redirecting to the second page the values in the session variables are printing but at top of the page i am getting the below error

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists in /home/udoo/public_html/flights/booking_details.php on line 2`

And when i am going back to the page one or some other page the same error is coming at the top infinite times.

What may the problem..??

Thanks in advance,

Shoba

Comment: possible duplicate off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464015/php-error-warning-session-start-function-session-start-node-no-longer-exi

Comment: Can you replace session_start() with @session_start and let us know ?

Comment: Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#89989.

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not a bug it is warning try using

```
@session_start();
```

instead of

```
session_start
```

at starting of file.

Comment: Now it is coming fine. But at the bottom of the page i am getting another error like `Warning: Unknown: Node no longer exists in Unknown on line 0`. How to rectify this..?

Comment: May be disable display errors using ini_set("display_errors", 0); at top if your page

Comment: Yes now its working perfectly..!! 

But in future it will not create any problem right...??

Why i am asking is previously that error is coming infinite time(Not stoping).

Comment: Oh ok fine then...

And finally one more thing What is the difference between `session_start()` and `@session_start()`

Comment: Oh ok ok ...Thnku Chandresh.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space from starting use like this  `<?php session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php OTHER CODE ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Go like this**

```
<?php
error_reporting( 0 );

//your code

?>
```

or

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

//your code
?>
```